# Principal.java:3: error: cannot find symbol rc.numero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

Tags: java

El motivo por el cual publico esto es por que tengo un problema referente al uso de "args", estoy haciendo un código que en la clase ecuaciones ingrese un número y le saque su raíz cuadrada y el parámetro del resultado lo mande hacia la clase Principal, mi problema es que me da un problema.

Clase ecuaciones:

```
public class Ecuaciones {
    public int numero;
    public double resultado;

    public static void sacarraiz(){

        Ecuaciones rc = new Ecuaciones();
        rc.numero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        rc.resultado=0;
        rc.resultado = Math.sqrt(rc.numero);
        System.out.println("el numero es:"+rc.numero);
        System.out.println("la raiz cuadrada del numero es:"+rc.resultado);
    }
}
```

Clase principal:

```
public class Principal{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Ecuaciones.sacarraiz();
    }
}
```

Y me aparece este error:

> ```
> Ecuaciones.java:10: error: cannot find symbol  
>    rc.numero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
>                                 ^
>  symbol:   variable args
>  location: class Ecuaciones
> 1 error
> ```

En mi lógica tiene que ver con que no declare un `public static main` en la sección donde ingreso los argumentos pero si lo hago me aparece otro error tipo **ilegal star expression**.

Comment: `args` esta declarado en el método main de querer hacer uso de este tu método `sacarraiz` tendria que recibir como parametro un array de  String  `sacarraiz(String[]args)` y en la clase principal es donde deber instancia el objeto rc ,ya solo usas `rc.sacarraiz(args)`

Comment: @Dramaturgo gracias por el consejo, lo implemente y al indagar un poco acerca de las instancias y objeto lo pude comprender y disculpa si no pude contestar, me quede sin luz debido a una tormenta de arena

Answer (score 0):

> (No comentaré en este caso la forma que tienes para realizar tu algoritmo, solo me preocuparé por darte el ejemplo para que puedas solucionar tu problema)

El compilador no puede encontrar el array `args` que utilizas en la clase *Ecuaciones*, ¿Por qué? pues porque nunca la instancias ni la pasas como parámetro como bien te comentó el usuario *Dramaturgo*.

La solución es simple:

Puedes pasar por parámetro el array *args* o pasar por parámetro el número entero con el que realizarás cualquier operación, en este caso y para mi gusto preferiría recibir como parámetro un número de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Ecuaciones {
    public int numero;
    public double resultado;

    public static void sacarraiz(int numero) {
        Ecuaciones rc = new Ecuaciones();
        rc.numero = numero;
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Y en tu clase *Principal*:

```
public class Principal{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Aquí lo más correcto seria validar que se haya pasado un valor entero en el "args"
        Ecuaciones.sacarraiz(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```